# ¿Porque la sentencia $stmt -> execute() me devuelve falso en php?

Tags: php, pdo

Estoy trabajando con PDO en PHP tengo un CRUD para las consultas, en la vista llamo al controlador y en el controlador llamo al modelo del CRUD para ejecutar la sentencia, no sé por qué me está regresando falso, el código es el siguiente:

```
$stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("INSERT INTO $tabla(nombre, 
    paterno, 
    fechaReserva, 
    correo, 
    checkin, 
    noches, 
    personas, 
    comentarios, 
    huesped satisfecho, 
    habitacion) VALUES(:nombre,
                       :paterno,
                       :fechaReserva,
                       :correo,
                       :checkin,
                       :noches,
                       :personas,
                       :comentarios,
                       :satisfecho,
                       :habitacion)");

    $stmt -> bindParam(":nombre", $datosModel["nombre"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt -> bindParam(":paterno", $datosModel["paterno"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt -> bindParam(":fechaReserva", $datosModel["fechaReserva"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt -> bindParam(":correo", $datosModel["email"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt -> bindParam(":checkin", $datosModel["checkin"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt -> bindParam(":noches", $datosModel["numeroNoches"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt -> bindParam(":personas", $datosModel["numeroPersonas"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt -> bindParam(":comentarios", $datosModel["comentarios"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt -> bindParam(":satisfecho", $datosModel["satisfecho"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt -> bindParam(":habitacion", $datosModel["habitacion"], PDO::PARAM_STR);

var_dump($datosModel);
var_dump($stmt -> execute());
```

Cabe mencionar que el array $datosModel que recibe como parametro la funcion junto con $tabla traen los datos que le mando en el controlador, no me marca ningun error simplemente al ejecutar regresa false, el var_dump del array tiene la siguiente información:

```
array (size=16)
  'nombre' => &string 'prueba' (length=6)
  'paterno' => &string 'prueba' (length=6)
  'fechaReserva' => &string 'prueba' (length=6)
  'email' => &string 'prueba' (length=6)
  'habitacion' => &string 'habitacion' (length=10)
  'canalReservacion' => &string 'Selecciona' (length=10)
  'descuento' => &string 'prueba' (length=6)
  'costoTotal' => &string 'prueba' (length=6)
  'presento' => &string 'si' (length=2)
  'checkin' => &string 'prueba' (length=6)
  'numeroNoches' => &string 'prueba' (length=6)
  'numeroPersonas' => &string 'prueba' (length=6)
  'tipoPago' => &string 'default' (length=7)
  'comentarios' => &string 'prueba' (length=6)
  'pagoObligatorio' => &string 'si' (length=2)
  'satisfecho' => &string 'si' (length=2)
```

Comment: Yo revisaría lo siguiente: 1. Si la variable `$tabla` es realmente la tabla que corresponde; 2. Si los nombres de columna están bien escritos en el `INSERT`... Por cierto, ¿tienes una columna llamada `huesped satisfecho`? No me parece una muy buena idea. 3. Si en el `bindParam` se está indicando el tipo de datos correcto. Por ejemplo ¿ `noches` no es del tipo `INT` en la base de datos? Si revisando todo eso no funciona puedes imprimir el error que arroja `$stmt`, o revisar el log de errores. Te dirá con exactitud lo que ocurre. Otra cosa, debes asegurarte de que la conexión está funcionando.

Comment: Justo venía a comentar lo de el campo huesped satisfecho que menciona @A.Cedano en su comentario. Yo añadiría que por lo que veo en tus campos, no parece que todos sean del tipo cadena en tu bd como para que lo definas así en el bind(). Atento con los valores booleanos y enteros.

Comment: Es posible que se esté dando una `exception` , para esto es importante poder asignar el atributo `$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` a la conexión `PDO`

Answer (score 0):

En primer lugar al construir una conexión por PDO , podría añadir el atributo `PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE` para tener reporte de exceptions , warnings. lo cuál hará que muestre antes de `var_dump`  si ha ocurrido alguna `exception` como parece ser el caso.

```
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

En segundo lugar , atacando directamente el problema, puede que el error sea en la sintaxis del `insert` al tener columna con espacio *(huesped satisfecho)*  lo cuál podría solucionar añadiendo un `backtick`  a los nombres de las columnas para que `MySQL` lo tome como una cadena literal y su utilidad son como para estos casos cuando se tiene tablas o columnas con espacios.  *( su prepared statemet podría quedar)*

```
 $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("INSERT INTO $tabla(`nombre`, `paterno`, 
                 `fechaReserva`,`correo`, `checkin`, `noches`, `personas`, 
                 `comentarios`, `huesped satisfecho`, `habitacion`)

               VALUES(:nombre,:paterno,:fechaReserva,:correo,
                     :checkin,:noches,:personas,:comentarios,:satisfecho,:habitacion)");
```